# Custom setter/willSet for Realm Object

Tags: swift, realm

Whenever I set a property of a Realm object I want to trigger the change of an other object that represents the object on my remote backend.

I was wondering if this is still the best practice recommended:

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/870#issuecomment-54543539

What I was trying to do, but doesn't work because it interferes with Realm:

```
dynamic var name: String = "" {
    willSet(newValue) {
        self.name = newValue
        self.widgetRemote?.name = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the workaround suggested in [realm/realm-cocoa#870](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/870#issuecomment-54543539) is still the best way to achieve this. For your case you'd want to do something like:

```
@objc private dynamic var backingName = ""

var name : String {
    get {
        return backingName
    }
    set(newValue) {
        backingName = newValue
        widgetRemote?.name = newValue
    }
}

override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["name"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

bdash's version in objc:

```
+(NSArray<NSString *> *)ignoredProperties
{
    return @[ @"name" ];
}
```

see the answer bdash's swiftly provided to obtain more context on backing store exampt from persistence into realm store

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation would [greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.